# Yield return incorrect usage

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, yield-return

I have this code:

```
    private IEnumerable<StatsSnapshot> ProcessPeriodicities(ICollection<StatsSnapshot> newStats)
    {
        foreach (var s in newStats)
        {
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastMinute);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastHour);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastDay);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastWeek);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastMonth);
        }
    }
```

and this function

```
    private StatsSnapshot ProcessPeriodicity(StatsSnapshot newStat, PeriodicityEnum p)
    {
        // ....
    }
```

I would like the `ProcessPeriodicities` function to return the "concatenation" of every `ProcessPeriodicity` results, but it is only returning the first one - it returns right after the first call (`yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, PeriodicityEnum.LastMinute);`)

What must I change, I am obviously using the `yield return` concept incorrectly...

Edit : the `ProcessPeriodicities` call:

```
    public ICollection<StatsSnapshot> ProcessStats(ICollection<StatsSnapshot> newStats)
    {
        var result = ProcessPeriodicities(newStats)
            .Where(i => i != null)
            .ToArray();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `ProcessPeriodicities`? If you use a `foreach`, it will correctly process *the entire* result set for `LastMinute` before even attempting to call `LastHour`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto see my edit

Comment: Please see the following .NET Fiddle. It should help understand how it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HttzuO

Comment: thanks @CamiloTerevinto - I am not sure to understand...from your fiddle, you are using the yield return exactly the same as me, but it's working? Do I have something wrong in my code or I just debugged incorrectly...

Comment: No, you are using it correctly. The debugger is tricking you into believing otherwise. `yield return` will return the debugger to the caller, the caller will process every item and then the debugger will return to the following line (`LastHour` in your case, `2` in my fiddle). Notice that the caller is `ToArray()`, as the `.Where()` call does not enumerate the source, so you have to F11 all the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CamiloTerevinto's explanation, it seems I am using the keyword correctly. See [his fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HttzuO) (in the question comments) to understand better what is happening

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        var list = new List<StatsSnapshot>();
        list.Add(new StatsSnapshot());
        list.Add(new StatsSnapshot());

        var result = ProcessPeriodicities(list)
            .Where(i => i != null)
            .ToArray();
    }


    private static IEnumerable<StatsSnapshot> ProcessPeriodicities(ICollection<StatsSnapshot> newStats)
    {
        foreach (var s in newStats)
        {
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, 1);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, 2);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, 3);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, 4);
            yield return ProcessPeriodicity(s, 5);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished a foreach loop");
        }


    }

    private static StatsSnapshot ProcessPeriodicity(StatsSnapshot s, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);

        return s;
    }
}

public class StatsSnapshot
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is just syntactic sugar for a `while` loop that iterates through an `IEnumerable`.

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

is literally

```
using (var messageEnumerator = message.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (messages.MoveNext())
    {
        var message = messages.Current;

        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

`yield return "whatever"` just makes `MoveNext` return true, and `Current` return `"whatever"`. Whereas `yield break` just makes `MoveNext` return false.

This should explain why the debugger is jumping back and forth.